# Не удалось установить Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Всем доброго!
После переустановки винды переустановил visual studio. Выбрал что мне нужно установить и пошла установка.
По завершению не установился пакет AspNet45.Feature.

Не удалось установить пакет "Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature,version=16.0.28315.86".
URL-адрес поиска
https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=2
Сведения
Команда выполнена: "C:\Windows\system32\dism.exe" /online /quiet /norestart /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:"netfx4extended-aspnet45" /All /logPath:"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20201210192332_001_Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature.log"
Код возврата: 2
Сведения о коде возврата: Не удается найти указанный файл.
Журнал
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20201210192332_001_Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature.log
Затронутые рабочие нагрузки
ASP.NET и разработка веб-приложений (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=16.8.30509.167)
Затронутые компоненты
Расширенные возможности ASP.NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AspNet45,version=16.0.28315.86)

Как я понял нету файла того что нужно для установки. Где лучше его скачать чтобы не хватануть какой то беды? И сталкивался с этим кто то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так народ.
Я хоть и в который раз подтверждаю свой ник, но вопреки этому я разобрался.
Суть в том что при установке Visual Studio случился сбой, из-за того что моя ОС Windows повреждена(или некоторые файлы).
И получается, то что у меня нету соответствующего обновления, в котором те компоненты обновлены до той версии, которого запрашивает VS Insttaler.
Подробнее описал Xiu Li здесь - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/666358/packageidmicrosoftvisualstudioaspnet45featurepacka-106.html