# Здравствуйте всем. При установке Visual Studio 2019 не удается установить пакет Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature. версия 16.11.9

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

попытка устранить проблему по ниже приведенным шагам не удалось (не смог найти файлы с таким названием кроме DISM (DISM:

1. Выполните следующую команду: DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth.
   Примечание. Выполнение команды может занять несколько минут.
2. Выполните следующую команду: DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup
3. Запустите следующую команду: sfc /scannow
   Примечание. Выполнение команды может занять несколько минут.
4. Включить TrustedInstaller sc config trustinstaller start=auto
   перезагрузите систему.) - DISM.exe файл (консоль) закрывается при нажатии.

подскажите пожалуйста  внятный способ устранения данной проблемы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1217273/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-microsoft-visualstudio-aspnet45-feature

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Обновите винду.